# Event Listener Symfony

Tags: entity-framework, symfony

I want to update the field of another entity , when an update is made to an entity.

I keep on " last_buy " the last date of purchase.

I want from my query to the repository and the data obtained , the method setLastBuy information is saved with the last purchase Offers entity.

It is that my ' Buy ' entity store modification date of the date of the last purchase of the entity offers.

But when I update my entity offers , I get the error:

Error: Call to a member function setLastBuy() on a non-object

```
namespace MyAppBundle\AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

use MyAppBundle\AppBundle\Entity\Offers;

class UpdateModified
    {
        public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args){

            $entity = $args->getEntity();
            $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager(); 

            if ($entity instanceof Offers)  {

                $offers   = $entityManager->getRepository('MyAppBundle:Buy')->findOffersByBuy($entity);
                $last_buy = $entity->getUpdatedAt();

                foreach($offers as $updateDate){
                    $updateDate->setLastBuy($last_buy);
                    $entityManager->persist($updateDate);
                }
                $entityManager->flush(); 
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the variable $offers is an array but not an array of Buy Objects. So i bet that you did something wrong in your BuyRepository class. Maybe you forgot to call the getResult() function or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would recommend is to write your own [EventSubscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) for your Offers Entity and then [dispatch](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/introduction.html) your Buy entity on Update, delete, etc.

Secondly:

```
if ($entity instanceof Offers)  { //$entity is of type Offers

    $offers   = $entityManager->getRepository('MyAppBundle:Buy')->findOffersByBuy($entity);
    //Offers above is empty array! 
    //findOfferByBuy() where passed entity is not a Buy object will return empty resultset
    $last_buy = $entity->getUpdatedAt();

    foreach($offers as $updateDate){
        //$pdateDate is null 
        $updateDate->setLastBuy($last_buy); //throw error 
        $entityManager->persist($updateDate);
    }

    $entityManager->flush(); 
}
```

Comment: My code works, thanks for your reply. 

My error is that in my repository not have a method getResult.

Comment: I'd say this answer is way more informative and well structured given the question you posted.